# Выложить однотипные приложения на GooglePlay

Tags: android, ios, google-play, appstore

У меня есть приложение, которое в дальнейшем будет катомизироваться под различных заказчиков. При этом под кастомизацией понимается смена иконки и логотипов внутри приложения. Есть ли возможность выкладывать на Google Play такие приложения под одним аккаунтом? Т.е. у меня есть клиент ИП "Вася Пупкин" он дает мне логотип и иконку, я собираю приложение и выкладываю на Google Play приложение "Вася Пупкин". Потом приходит кто-то еще, я делаю сборку с новый иконкой и логотипом и иыкладываю еще одно приложение, которое отличается только названием, иконкой и логотипом.
Аналогичный вопрос про AppStore.

Спасибо

Comment: Посмотрите пример аппликаций `FANDOM`, их публикует fandom wiki под разные темы разные приложения, может поможет.

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете выкладывать даже полностью идентичные приложения, если у них будет изменён `application id`, т.е. пакет. Т.е. меняйте это значение при сборке нового приложения и всё будет работать.